# define: expected a variable, but found a part

Tags: racket

I am getting define error from the function neighbours-in-grid below, do I need to use "let" to declare from inside the define???

```
;; Purpose: Produce a maze, being a list of whole numbers (cells) 
;; between 0 and the square of grid-size (grid-size^2)
;; The list prepresenting the maze will start with 0 and be expanded 
;; by randomly picking a cell already in the maze
;;  then randomly selecting a neighbouring cell (horz and vert axis 
;; only) following tests to ensure that the new neighbouring cell is:
;   a) within the grid/maze area
;   b) not already in the maze
;   c) not adjacent to a cell already in the maze (otherwide could block the maze path)
;   d) will likely add tests here to make sure maze does not consume itself
; Grid will lay out as follows (assuming grid-size is 3;
;   0  1  2
;   3  4  5
;   6  7  8

(define grid-size 15)
(define a-maze (list 0))

;Is returned value part of the existing a-maze
(check-expect (member? (random-cell a-maze) a-maze)
          #true)
;Is returned vale a number?
(check-expect (number? (random-cell a-maze))
          #true)

;Is returned value within the limits of the grid
(check-expect (<= 0 (random-cell a-maze) (sqr grid-size))
          #true)

;random-cell: non-empty list -> random number from list
(define (random-cell a-list)
   (list-ref a-list (random (length a-list))))


(check-expect (member? 15 (neighbours (random-cell a-maze))) #true)
(check-expect (member? 1 (neighbours (random-cell a-maze))) #true)
(check-expect (member? -1 (neighbours (random-cell a-maze))) #true)
(check-expect (member? -15 (neighbours (random-cell a-maze))) #true)



(check-expect (= (length (neighbours-in-grid (random-cell a-maze))) 2) #true)

;neighbours: non-empty whole number representing a cell -> list of     
;neighbouring cells - use horz and vert axis only (no diagonals)
(define (neighbours member-cell)
  (list (+ member-cell grid-size) ;cell below
        (+ member-cell 1) ;cell immediate right
        (- member-cell 1) ;cell immediate left
        (- member-cell grid-size) ;cell above
      )

   )

  ;neighbours-in-grid: non-empty list of potential neighbours -> narrowed list of validated neighbours that are in the grid
(define (neighbours-in-grid (neighbours (random-cell a-maze)))
  (cond [(< 0 (first neighbours) > grid-size) (remove (first neighbours))]
        [(< 0 (second neighbours) > grid-size) (remove (second neighbours))]
        [(< 0 (third neighbours) > grid-size) (remove (third neighbours))]
        [(< 0 (fourth neighbours) > grid-size) (remove (fourth neighbours))]
       ))
```

Comment: I am trying to get the result of the function neighbours to go into the function heighbours-in-grid

Comment: Yep, that's fine. That means that when you *call* the neighbours-in-grid function, you'll want to use the neighbors function. So, for instance, your check-expect might contain of the form `(neighbours-in-grid (neighbours (random-cell a-maze))`.

Comment: DrRacket's 'stepper' tool might be useful to you here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here has to do with the first line of your `neighbours-in-grid` function.

Specifically, a function is defined using this shape:

```
(define (<name-of-function> <name-of-argument> ...)
   <body-of-function>)
```

Your function's first line looks like this:

```
(define (neighbours-in-grid (neighbours (random-cell a-maze)))
  (cond ...))
```

This doesn't fit the pattern. What are the names of the arguments? Based on the code that follows this line, it looks to me like you want a single argument, named `neighbours`.  If so, this code should instead read:

```
(define (neighbours-in-grid neighbours)
   (cond ...))
```

I think part of the confusion here may stem from the fact that separately, you have a *function* named neighbours.